# A considerable time gap noted between two Spring components picking messages from ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mule, activemq-classic

We are using ActiveMQ 5.15.

We have a system where we follow orchestration model to process the messages. So let us say we have 2 Spring components which are independent from each other. There is an orchestrator component that sends first to Component-1 and then once the response is received then it goes to Component-2.

What we see is there is a huge difference between the time the first message came out from Component-1 and the time the second message was picked by Component-2. Can any of you suggest what could be the reason. We could see almost like 1 second time difference between these 2.

Comment: Do you have any logging in place to help determine where the time is actually being taken? If so, you should share that data. If not, you should gather that data and then share it.

Comment: This is happening at Mule AMQ dispatcher and the other side the Spring MVC consumer level. Please let me know how can I take the logs?

Comment: You should provide more details of the architecture, Spring components, versions used. Some thread dumps maybe useful for analysis. You didn't mention any Mule interactions. Why did you add the Mule tag?

Comment: Configuring logging for your application components and ActiveMQ is a much larger question than the one you've asked here. I recommend you ask a new question specifically about logging if you need help in this regard.

Comment: Thanks all, I identified the situation and got it resolved